# How to determine the boson of a given particle decay?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

How do I know which of the SM forces take part at a given particle decay? For example, look at the following decay:

$$\tau^- + \nu_{\tau} \rightarrow \ell +  \bar \nu_{\ell}$$

This decay takes place via a $W^-$ boson. I'm now wondering, if the force carrier must be the $W^-$ boson and can't just be a photon or $Z$ boson. In other words, how can I determine which force is necessary for a given particle decay?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replaced the $W^-$ with a $Z^0$ or $\gamma$, (electrical) charge would not be conserved at each vertex.

Since you have a change in lepton flavour, it has be the weak interaction. If it were just a scattering event, with no charge transfer, then it might be either EM ($\gamma$) or weak ($Z^0$), albeit with different probability amplitudes.